# Google Maps API v3 add markers to map

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps-api-3

I have got GoogleMaps (api v3) marker coordinates in a GridView in my asp.net site. I would like to show those markers in the map. The problem is the markers are top of each other. All marker is  on the first markers coordinate. There are so more markers then I have got in the GridView (markers are draggable).

```
//.aspx
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&key=xyz"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //google maps API v3

    //változók

    var GMLat = '<%= Label_GMLat.Text %>';
    var GMLng = '<%= Label_GMLng.Text %>';
    var GMHirdetesID = [];
    var GMLatLng = [];
    var GMKep = [];
    var GMTitle = [];
    var GMIngatlanCim = [];
    var GMSzoveg = [];
    var Grid_Table = '';
    var hirdetesid = '';
    var lat = '';
    var lng = '';
    var kep = '';
    var title = '';
    var ingatlancim = '';
    var szoveg = '';
    var latlng_1 = new google.maps.LatLng(49, 17);    //(GMLat, GMLng);
    var marker_1_pos = latlng_1;
    var map;
    var marker_1;
    var infowindow_1;
    var infowindow_1_off = true;

    //funkciók

    //init
    function initialize() {
        var myOptions =
        {
            zoom: 8,
            center: latlng_1,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            mapTypeControl: true,
            mapTypeControlOptions:
            {
                style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU,
                poistion: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT,
                mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                             google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
                             google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
                             google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE]
            },
            navigationControl: true,
            navigationControlOptions:
            {
                style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL   //ZOOM_PAN; SMALL; ANDROID
            },
            scaleControl: true,
            disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
            draggable: true,
            streetViewControl: true,
            draggableCursor: 'move'
        }

        //térkép
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
        Grid_Table = document.getElementById('<%= GridView1.ClientID %>');
        //tömbök föltöltése
        for (var row = 1; row < Grid_Table.rows.length; row++) {
            for (var col = 0; col < Grid_Table.rows[row].cells.length; col++) {
                if (col == 0) {
                    if (document.all)
                        hirdetesid = Grid_Table.rows[row].cells[col].innerText;
                    else
                        hirdetesid = Grid_Table.rows[row].cells[col].textContent;
                }
                if (col == 3) {
                    lat = '';
                    if (document.all)
                        lat = Grid_Table.rows[row].cells[col].innerText;
                    else
                        lat = Grid_Table.rows[row].cells[col].textContent;
                }
                if (col == 4) {
                    lng = '';
                    if (document.all)
                        lng = Grid_Table.rows[row].cells[col].innerText;
                    else
                        lng = Grid_Table.rows[row].cells[col].textContent;
                }
                if (col == 5) {
                    if (document.all)
                        ingatlancim = Grid_Table.rows[row].cells[col].innerText;
                    else
                        ingatlancim = Grid_Table.rows[row].cells[col].textContent;
                }
                if (col == 6) {
                    if (document.all)
                        title = Grid_Table.rows[row].cells[col].innerText;
                    else
                        title = Grid_Table.rows[row].cells[col].textContent;
                }
                if (col == 7) {
                    if (document.all)
                        szoveg = Grid_Table.rows[row].cells[col].innerText;
                    else
                        szoveg = Grid_Table.rows[row].cells[col].textContent;
                }
                if (col == 8) {
                    if (document.all)
                        kep = Grid_Table.rows[row].cells[col].innerText;
                    else
                        kep = Grid_Table.rows[row].cells[col].textContent;
                }
                GMHirdetesID.push(hirdetesid);
                GMLatLng.push(new google.maps.LatLng(GMLat, GMLng));
                GMKep.push(kep);
                GMTitle.push(title);
                GMIngatlanCim.push(ingatlancim);
                GMSzoveg.push(szoveg);
            }
            //align(GMLatLng);
            //markerek fölrakása
                for (var i = 0; i <= GMHirdetesID.length; i++) {
                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        position: GMLatLng[i],
                        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                        draggable: true
                    });

                    (function (i, marker) {
                        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                            if (!infowindow) {
                                infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                            }
                            infowindow.setContent("Message " + i);
                            //infowindow.SetSize(300, 200);
                            infowindow.open(map, marker);
                        });
           /**/         google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () { infowindow.open(map, marker) });
                    })(i, marker);
            }
        }
    // google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () { infowindow.open(map, marker) });
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function () { infowindow.close() });
    }
    // Onload handler to fire off the app.
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>

    <div style=" width: 1000px; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;">
        Térkép:
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataKeyNames="HirdetesID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Width="1000px">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HirdetesID" HeaderText="HirdetesID" ReadOnly="True"
                    SortExpression="HirdetesID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="Email" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Coord" HeaderText="Coord" SortExpression="Coord" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Lat" SortExpression="Lat" NullDisplayText=" " />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Lng" SortExpression="Lng" NullDisplayText=" " />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="IngatlanCim" HeaderText="IngatlanCim" 
                    SortExpression="IngatlanCim" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="GoogleMapsTitle" HeaderText="GoogleMapsTitle" 
                    SortExpression="GoogleMapsTitle" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="GoogleMapsSzoveg" HeaderText="GoogleMapsSzoveg" 
                    SortExpression="GoogleMapsSzoveg" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Prp_keputvonal_thumb" 
                    HeaderText="Prp_keputvonal_thumb" SortExpression="Prp_keputvonal_thumb" >
                </asp:BoundField>
            </Columns>
            <EditRowStyle Width="1000px" />
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:PROPYTESZT_ConnectionString1 %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT tblGoogleMapsCoord.HirdetesID, tblGoogleMapsCoord.Email, tblGoogleMapsCoord.Coord, tblGoogleMapsCoord.IngatlanCim, tblGoogleMapsCoord.GoogleMapsTitle, tblGoogleMapsCoord.GoogleMapsSzoveg, Prp_kep.Prp_keputvonal_thumb FROM tblGoogleMapsCoord LEFT OUTER JOIN Prp_kep ON tblGoogleMapsCoord.HirdetesID = Prp_kep.Prp_hirdetes WHERE (Prp_kep.Prp_GoogleMapsKep = N'igen') OR (Prp_kep.Prp_GoogleMapsKep IS NULL)">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
        <br />
        <br />
    </div>
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 800px; height: 600px; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;"></div>
    <div style="width: 800px; text-align: left; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;">
        GMLat: <asp:Label ID="Label_GMLat" runat="server" Text="Label_GMLat"></asp:Label><br />
        GMLng: <asp:Label ID="Label_GMLng" runat="server" Text="Label_GMLng"></asp:Label><br />
        GMTitle: <asp:Label ID="Label_GMTitle" runat="server" Text="" Visible="True"></asp:Label><br />
        GMIngatlanCim: <asp:Label ID="Label_GMIngatlanCim" runat="server" Text="" Visible="True"></asp:Label><br />
        GMSzoveg: <asp:Label ID="Label_GMSzoveg" runat="server" Text="" Visible="True"></asp:Label><br />
        GMLink: <asp:Label ID="Label_GMLink" runat="server" Text="" Visible="True"></asp:Label><br />
        GMKep: <asp:Label ID="Label_GMKep" runat="server" Text="" Visible="True"></asp:Label><br />
        MegjelenitesAdatok(error): <asp:Label ID="Label_MegjelenitesAdatok" runat="server" Text="" Visible="True"></asp:Label><br />
    </div>

//.aspx.cs
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string HirdetesID = "";
        string GMCoord = "";
        string GMLat = "";
        string GMLng = "";
        int GMindex;
        int test1;
    /*GridView1 Lat és Lng oszlopainak feltöltése Coord oszlopa alapján*/
        for (int i = 1; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            GMCoord = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Text;
            GMCoord = GMCoord.Replace("(", "");
            GMCoord = GMCoord.Replace(")", "");
            GMLat = GMCoord;
            GMLng = GMCoord;
            GMindex = GMCoord.IndexOf(",");
            test1 = GMLat.Length - GMindex;
            GMLat = GMLat.Remove(GMindex, (GMLat.Length - GMindex));
            GMLng = GMLng.Remove(0, GMindex+1);
            GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Text = GMLat;
            GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Text = GMLng;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you give more detail? Is the problem that the markers are all in the same location and they should have different values? Or that all the markers _are_ actually in the same location and having many markers on top of each other creates an undesirable display? Can you include a link or maybe an image?

Comment: Or: post the code from the browser, not the server, because it's the browser which does all the work. Or post a link. You don't appear to have assigned a useful value to `Grid_Table`, for example.

Comment: The markers should be in different locations, dut they are the same location. There should be 4 marker, but there are mutch more then 4.

Comment: [the picture](http://kepfeltoltes.hu/120503/N_vteleng_www.kepfeltoltes.hu_.png)

Comment: Have you tried looping through the data and dumping it out to see if it contains what you expect? It is likely you have a data problem or some kind of looping logic problem.

Comment: I got help, I should update line "GMLatLng.push(new google.maps.LatLng(GMLat, GMLng));" to "GMLatLng.push(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng));".
My markers are the right position, but one position are a lot of marker.

Comment: Great, glad it is resolved. When you answer your own question, it's customary on stackoverflow for you to post the answer yourself and then accept the answer. It lets others know that the question has been answered and allows them to easily find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

update line 
"GMLatLng.push(new google.maps.LatLng(GMLat, GMLng));" to 
"GMLatLng.push(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng));"

Answer (score 0):

Did you try?

```
for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var data = markers[i]
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
            lat_lng.push(myLatlng);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                title: data.title
            });
            latlngbounds.extend(marker.position);
            (function (marker, data) {
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                    infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                });
            })(marker, data);
        }
        map.setCenter(latlngbounds.getCenter());
        map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);
```